# How do you access dom selectors using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have a simple script that would add a class to a dom selector.

```
showParent() {
  console.log('show parent');
  $("seasonsGrid").toggleClass("grid-layout");
}
```

How does angular allow you to target these dom nodes whether they are tags or named elements?

in this case `$("seasonsGrid")` is a reference to

```
@Component({ selector: 'seasonsGrid', ...
```

but would be useful to know how to dom traverse using tags and named el's.

what would the ng2 equivalent be for this

```
var seasonsGrid = $(seasonsGrid);
```

Comment: I don't know any angular 2, but is the "ng-class" directive not available?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html might help

Comment: `selector: 'seasonsGrid'` corresponds to `seasons-grid` element. But you should use ngClass directive.

Answer (score 2):

You could take use of [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html)/[`Renderer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Renderer-class.html) to get component element

```
import {Component, View, ElementRef} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {NgClass} from 'angular2/common'; //import when you wanted to use ngClass
import {Renderer} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({ selector: 'seasonsGrid', ...})
export class MyComponent {
   let el: any; 
   let componentElement:any;
   constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){
      //el = elementRef.nativeElement;
      componentElement = renderer.selectRootElement(); //will have component root element
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
       console.log(el); //nativeElement to process
       console.log(componentElement); //nativeElement to process
   }
}
```

But in your case you can think of to have `ngClass` directive to have it in a place like `[ngClass]="{className: expression}"`

Comment: I must need to do some more homework but from the looks of it angular 2 is by far more convoluted if all that is required just to initialize the states of a toggle class on an element. jquery is 1 line `$("seasonsGrid").toggleClass("grid-layout");`

Comment: @ndesign11 it's not a dom manipulation library like jquery, so it is a little more work. angular 1 has jqlite, im not sure angular 2 does, but it has other methods of getting the same effect.

Comment: Angular2 doesn't have library like jQLite(Angular1 have it). But A2 does provided an API [BrowserDomAdapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/BrowserDomAdapter-class.html) to have access to DOM by putting wrapper over native DOM query methods..

Answer (score 1):

> I must need to do some more homework but from the looks of it angular 2 is by far more convoluted if all that is required just to initialize the states of a toggle class on an element. jquery is 1 line

Angular 2 is a data-driven reactive framework.  Instead of thinking about selectors and DOM manipulation code, I encourage you to embrace Angular-think, which is quite different from jQuery-think.

If you want to change a class in a data-driven framework, you first declaratively bind some data to that element's class property in a component template.  Then, to change the class, you simply change the bound data.  As others have already mentioned, `NgClass` is the way to do that.

Similarly, component logic should not manipulate the DOM (i.e., it shouldn't call things like `toggleClass()`), rather it should change data or emit an event (up to its parent).

When Angular change detection runs, it will notice the data changes and update the DOM (or native UI) or propagate the data change to a parent component (for an emitted event) or to a child component (for an input data property change).

Angular-think is all about data-driven changes.  And Angular 2 pushes us further down that road than Angular 1 did. (That's a good thing.)

Comment: I can appreciate data driven/reactive changes but there is also the concerns of usability and user interaction. Instantiating views by `toggling` on off button. It seems very difficult to achieve this. I have to create a class/service and then import it all over the place.

Comment: @ndesign11, I don't have enough information to comment back about that.  I suggest you create a new SO question (it sounds like a good design/architecture question), since the question on this page seems nicely focused on DOM selectors.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't answer the question as I'm very new to NG2 (like three days), but here's a few things I've found in the documentation:

```
<div [class.isStopped] = "isStopped"></div>
<div [style.color] = "isStopped ? 'red' : 'blue'"></div>
<button [attr.aria-label] = "ok"></button>
<div [ngClass] = "{selected:isSelected}"></div>
```

ngClass is a Directive Property, just like ngStyle and ngModel.  For the most part, they just took out the dash.

While we're on Property Bindings:

```
<img [src] = "vehicle.imageUrl" />
<vehicle-detail [vehicle] = "currentVehicle"></vehicle-detail>
```

You tie the component (code) to the template so in this case it wouldn't be necessary to get the element in code and change it, just change the Component (view model).